# How to put like this maximum and minimum gross pay and number

Tags: python

How to make it right[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1ijC.png)
How to put like this maximum and minimum gross pay and number

Comment: you must make a dictionary instead of a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a list of gross_pays and you can get the maximum and minimum from the list
NUM_EMPLOYEES = int(input('Enter number of employees : '))

```
def main():

    hours = []

    number = 1

    for index in range (NUM_EMPLOYEES):
    
        employee = int(input(f"Enter the hours worked by employee {number}:"))
        number += 1
        hours.append(employee)
    
    pay_rate= float (input("Enter the hourly pay rate : "))
    
    number = 1
    gross_pay2 = []
    for index in hours:
    
        gross_pay = index * pay_rate 
        print (f"Goss pay for employee {number}: ${gross_pay}")
        gross_pay2.append(gross_pay)
        number += 1
    maximum=gross_pay2.index(max(gross_pay2))+1
    minimum=gross_pay2.index(min(gross_pay2))+1
    
    print(f'Employee {maximum} gets maximum gross pay: {max(gross_pay2)}') 
    print(f'Employee {minimum} gets minimum gross pay: {min(gross_pay2)}')

main()
```